# Thunderbird 15.0 - In options->copy to disappeared folder list

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird

In Thunderbird 15.0 on Kubuntu 12.04 64Bit disappeared the folder list in the copy to menu

To reproduce

- select write (new message) appears a new window
- select options
- selcet copy to - appears a little white point instead of the folder list

Same problem on two different notebooks; one upgraded from 11.04 and the other with a clean 12.04 installation.

Seems related to the 15.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [bug 1045196](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1045196).  An update is available for pre-testing in https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/ and will be pushed out at soon as it's been tested.  You can subscribe to the bug to see when the fix is released to the main archive if you wish.